# Как получить в представлении IQueryable<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Я пробовал писать вот так

```
@model IQueryable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
```

Но получаю исключение

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MvcMovie.Models.Movie]'.

Вот код контроллера:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string searchString)
    {
        var MovieQuery =
            from movie in db.Movie
            where movie.Title.Contains(searchString)
            select new { movie.Title, movie.Genre };

        return View(MovieQuery);
    }
```

Comment: У вас в контроллере явно вернулся не `IQueryable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>`, а результат селекта вида `.Select(m=> new {...}` - с анонимным типом вместо Movie. Покажите код контроллера.

Comment: Добавил код контроллера. Но вообще я хотел возвращать результаты с нескольких таблиц сразу, то есть просто написать select movie;(так работает) я не могу.

Comment: Создайте вью-модель, в которой будут все необходимые свойства для результата с нескольких таблиц. / Как вариант, можно использовать кортеж, но лучше вью-модель.

Comment: IQuerable во вью передавать это худшее что можно придумать. View должен только отображать данные, а не отправлять запросы в бд

Answer (score 3):

Тип значения, возвращаемого из контроллера должен совпадать с типом, ожидаемым моделью.

Добавьте новый тип модели, для этого конкретного представления, с полями Title и Genre.

```
// назовите на свой вкус
public class MovieInfo
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Genre {get;set;}
}
```

В контроллере создавайте экземпляр этой модели вместо анонимного типа.

```
... select new MovieInfo { Title = movie.Title, Genre = movie.Genre };
return View(MovieQuery.ToList()); // выполняйте запрос до передачи его в представление
```